# How do we handle question asking ref from a source where there is no reference?

Tags: discussion

Recently I came across on a question which is asking for a deity reference from a particular source, but the source has nowhere mentioning of that deity. The link to that question: [Are lord Ganesh ,Lord Subramanya Swamy and Lord Ayyappa are gods or demigods according to bhagavad geeta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37810/647)

Can we answer this question saying like "No there is no reference of this deity in this Source" ?
If not how to attempt to answer this type of question?

Comment: Yes. I have seen answers where they have negated the basis of the question (and they have been upvoted or accepted).